# Problema para obtener IP en Formulario de Contacto

Tags: php, formularios, ip

He decidido implementar un registro de IP en mi formulario de contacto, pero por alguna razón no funciona... Creo que falta implementar un atributo ".get_ip_address()", he intentado de todo, literalmente de todo, no sé que sucede. Ojo que el formulario funciona perfecto, salvo que no puedo hacer que envíe la IP dentro de el email saliente.

---

Esto está en la cabecera de mi web:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e){
        $("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#mail-status").hide();
            $('#send-message').hide();
            $('#loader-icon').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "contact.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json',
                data: {
                "name":$('input[name="name"]').val(),
                "email":$('input[name="email"]').val(),
                "content":$('textarea[name="content"]').val(),
                "ip":$('input[name="ip"]').val(),
                "g-recaptcha-response":$('textarea[id="g-recaptcha-response"]').val()},             
                success: function(response){
                $("#mail-status").show();
                $('#loader-icon').hide();
                if(response.type == "error") {
                    $('#send-message').show();
                    $("#mail-status").attr("class","error");                
                } else if(response.type == "message"){
                    $('#send-message').hide();
                    $("#mail-status").attr("class","success");                          
                }
                $("#mail-status").html(response.text);  
                },
                error: function(){} 
            });
        }));
    });

    //Lo que sigue es el código añadido para obtener la IP  

    function get_ip_address() {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } else {
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            } else {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
        }
        return $ip;
    }
</script>
```

---

Este es el código de Contact.php

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{
require('constant.php'); //Constant.php es para el Captcha

    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $content   = filter_var($_POST["content"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(empty($user_name)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Nombre</b>";     
    }
    if(empty($user_email)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Email</b>";
    }
    if(empty($content)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Mensaje</b>";
    }

    if(!empty($empty)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => implode(", ",$empty) . ' - Faltan estos datos.'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$user_email.'</b> email err&oacute;neo.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //reCAPTCHA validation
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

        require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');        

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

          if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>Captcha</b> Validaci&oacute;n requerida!'));
                die($output);               
          } 
    }

    $toEmail = "ejemplo@miweb.xx";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $user_name . "<" . $user_email . ">  " . $ip . " \r\n";
    if (mail($toEmail, "Formulario de Contacto", $content, $mailHeaders, $ip)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Mensaje enviado. Le responderemos a la brevedad.'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Error en el env&iacute;o, intente con otro m&eacute;todo.'.SENDER_EMAIL));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

---

Este es el código del formulario:

```
<form id="frmContact" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" id="ip" name="ip">
    <div class="input-field field">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre y/o Empresa" title="Ingrese su Nombre" class="form-control required" aria-required="true" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field field">         
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" title="Ingrese su dirección de Email" class="form-control required email" aria-required="true" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field field">         
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comment-content" name="content" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje..."></textarea>          
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" style="transform:scale(0.9);transform-origin:0 0" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>"></div>
    <div id="mail-status"></div>            
    <button class="btn btn-blue bgray btn-effect2" type="Submit" id="send-message" style="clear:both;">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos podrias obtener la ip algo asi:

```js
function getUserIP(onNewIP) {
    //compatibilidad para firefox y chrome
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({
        iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

    function iterateIP(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
    }


    pc.createDataChannel("");

    pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
        });
        
        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop); 


    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    };
}

// uso

getUserIP(function(ip){
  document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML = 'IP  : '  + ip;
});
```

```html
<span id="ip"></span>
```

Bien ahora en tu ajax no esta recibiendo la ip porque intentas obtenerla desde un input:

```
"ip":$('input[name="ip"]').val(),
```

si ya tienes una funcion la podrias obtener invocando a la misma:

```
"ip":get_ip_address(),
```

o  su vez antes de iniciar tu ajax obten la ip:

```
var mi_ip =  get_ip_address();
$.ajax({
...
```

y en tu ajax seria:

```
...
...
"ip": mi_ip,
...
..
```

espero te sirva..!!

..

Comment: Revisaré y apenas ande esto te aviso. Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicación.